# implicit conversion from double to string vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I try to run this code but iget the message   implicit conversion from double to string vb.net i try different conversion but its the same

```
 Private Sub TxtRemise_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtRemise.TextChanged
        Dim TotalTTc As Decimal
        TotalTTc = CDec(TotalHT.Text) + CDec(TXTMontantTva.Text)
        TxtTTC.Clear()

        TxtTTC.Text = TotalTTc) - val(TxtRemise.Text)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Here: it's an error `TxtTTC.Text = TotalTTc) - val(TxtRemise.Text)` have to be `TxtTTC.Text = TotalTTc - val(TxtRemise.Text)`.

Comment: Don't use `val`... if you can

Comment: Why are you using `Val`, which returns a `Double`, when you used `CDec` the first two times, which returns a `Decimal`? `CDec` is not great but `Val` is worse. If you're going to use `CDec` elsewhere then use it there too. I suspect that you may have done that because `CDec` was failing at times. `Val` is not a fix but a cover-up. What you should be doing is using `Decimal.TryParse` in all three cases and reporting any validation failures to the user.

Comment: The message is because you're assigning the calculation result (which is either `Double` or `Decimal`) to `TxtTTC.Text` which is `String`.  Since you don't provide your own conversion instruction (most commonly either the `CStr` operator or the `ToString` function on the result), the compiler inserts a conversion via a call of ToString for you, and it inserts the warning.  If you have `Option Strict On` (which is highly recommended) then the explicit conversion becomes mandatory, not just a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You perform a mathematical operation, which will obviously result in a number, and you then assign that to the `Text` property of a `TextBox`, which is type `String`. If you want to assign to a `String` property then you need to assign a `String`. If you have a number, that means calling `ToString` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. There was some little mistakes. Check my example and comment if you had the solution to your question, thank you.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub TxtRemise_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtRemise.TextChanged
    Dim TotalTTc As Decimal
    TotalTTc = CDec(TotalHT.Text) + CDec(TXTMontantTva.Text)
    TxtTTC.Clear()
    TxtTTC.Text = (TotalTTc - CDec(TxtRemise.Text)).ToString
End Sub
End Class
```